# Need help Looping Excel Solver for X number of times and putting details on a new tab

Tags: excel, loops, solver

I build a fantasy sports optimizer using EXCEL SOLVER.  It works great for spitting out 1 single lineup.  I want to upgrade this file to have the user choose a number say between 1-50 and then have it look through and make that multiple number of lineups.

This is the code that I currently have:

```
Sub OptoRun()
' OptoRun Macro
    SolverOk SetCell:="$AC$1", MaxMinVal:=1, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$Q$2:$Q$200", _
        Engine:=2, EngineDesc:="Simplex LP"
    SolverOk SetCell:="$AC$1", MaxMinVal:=1, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$Q$2:$Q$200", _
        Engine:=2, EngineDesc:="Simplex LP"
    SolverSolve UserFinish:=True
    Range("priorProjPts").Value = Range("totProjPts").Value - 0.01
End Sub
```

Adding in the Range formula at the end allows the user to hit the "optimize" button again and it will go to the next highest lineup, etc, etc.  I am wanting this to pit the lineups out on another page for the # they choose.  So for example the user would choose 10 lineups and hit optimize and it would provide 10 lineups.

Comment: Were you able to find your answer? I see below you ran into a problem with my code. Where you able to overcome this issue?

Comment: Yes I figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some guidiance as I am not very familiar with the SOLVER plug-in. I am also not even familiar with your excel workbook.

The below macro will help get you started. You will NEED TO MODIFY THIS CODE. If you run this as is, it WILL NOT DO MUCH.

```
Sub OptoRun()
    Dim currentPoint as Long

    NumberOfLoops = InputBox("How Many Lineups?")
    If NOT IsNumeric(NumberOfLoops) Then NumberOfLoops = 1

    currentPoint = 1

    Do until currentPoint > NumberOfLoops
        'Insert a modified version of your code here

        'use the (currentPoint) variable for the current position within the loop
        'Example: ActiveSheet.Cells(CurrentPoint, 1).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(CurrentPoint, 1).Address

        currentPoint = currentPoint + 1
    Loop

End Sub
```

I have placed a comment above on where you will insert your modified code. To determine the current position, you will use the variable `CurrentPoint`

This variable will return the current number within the loop, and can be used as a unique position.

For example, you could use something like this...

`ActiveSheet.Cells(CurrentPoint, 1).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(CurrentPoint, 1).Address`

The above will simply make anything between row 1, column 1 ($A$1) to whatever the input value (i.e. if 100 is input then $A$100) equal to the address. (i.e. if input 100, then everything between A1 and A100 will equal there cell address)

Now, it does appear that you are using the `Range` property, you might be able to achieve the same result by switching over to the Cells property, but you will not be able to use "Friendly Names."

Comment: Thank you for responding.  The loop works great.  The problem I run into is with my 2nd block of code I'm getting a run-time error '1004' - Application-defined or object-defined error.         Range("AH4:AH11").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("Lineup_VIEW").Select
        Range("A200").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
            False, Transpose:=True
        Range("A3").Select
        Sheets("Optimizer").Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False